# Variables of regex int php

Tags: php, regex, var

I get some strings like `phs(2.1.2):someinfo` and I want to receive a version (2.1.2) in variable with hel of php and it's regexp abilities.
I get it like:

```
        if (preg_match('/phs\((.*)\):/', $line))
        {
            echo $line.'<br>';
        }
```

It's ok, but now I want to get stored variable of regexp. I've found that I can get it as \1, but when I try it it's white screen in browser, so it doesn't work. Is it possible to get variables from regexp? Or there is better sollution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the optional parameter of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php),  `array &$matches` .
Something like this -

```
$line = "phs(2.1.2):someinfo";
if (preg_match('/phs\((.*)\):/', $line, $matches))
{
    $version = $matches[1];
    echo $version.'<br>';
}
//OUTPUT - 2.1.2
```

Comment: I'll accept your answers in 10 minutes when site will alow me to do this.